# Choosing a case for 5090x for heavy duty usage

Tags: processor, development, case, heat-sink

I am trying to choose a case from the following. I will be using a 5090x with a noctua 15 cooler, need to have space for a future 3080 graphic card and most importantly it needs to able to dissipate heat as good as possible.

Cases to choose from (Please only chose a case from the following, not others):

- Sharkoon RGB Slider ATX
- Sharkoon VG5-W ATX
- CoolerMaster MasterBox E501L Mid Tower
- Sharkoon VG7-W Window ATX
- Antec NX400 ATX Mid Tower Black Case
- Sharkoon PURE STEEL Full ATX
- CoolerMaster MasterBox K501L ATX Mid Towe
- Sharkoon REV100 ATX RGB
- Corsair 110R Tempered Glass Mid-Tower
- ADATA XPG STARKER ATX Mid Tower
- Corsair Carbide 275R Acrylic Mid-Towe
- Corsair 110Q Mid-Tower Quiet
- CoolerMaster MasterBox MB511 Mesh ATX Red Case No PSU

Note: I don't care about rgb and those kind of game

Thank you very much for your much appreciated help.

Comment: From [this answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1529892/347380), you want the one with airflow most like the second image & least like the first.

Comment: @Tetsujin Not to be too harsh but there are a few issues with the answer that you've given there. For one, the mac example has a layout that is not compatible with PC hardware. 
The PC case airflow is based on front low back high design, one that has been used in PC cases for years now. the "no airflow" place are 5.25 bays. and the psu is mounted so that air is pulled in from the bottom and ejected at the back, it does not impact case airflow.
Lastly pc parts are wildly different so a more general airflow approach is required. The "bad" example is one of the better cases of 2011

Comment: @BobMeijer -  I'm not a CFD specialist, but a friend of mine is - he has a doctorate on the subject & is a university professor teaching it. I'll take my cues from him ;)) His own, home built-case is remarkably similar to the Apple design, with exceptions made for where that can't be adhered to because of mobo design. Just because they've always been made that way does not make them a good design, merely 'accepted' for what they are.

Comment: @Tetsujin The reason for their design is compatibility, Apple makes all the parts in house and can tightly integrate them. Something pc case builders cant do without limiting their options. that case you chose also has to support [this](https://www.corsair.com/corsairmedia/sys_master/productcontent/CC600TWM-WHT-600T_010.png) Multiple gpu's and different cpu cooling sollutions. Also I think your CFD specialist friend must agree that no airflow in a place where a dvd drive goes is not a problem, but an arrow claiming the cables pull air into a psu is.

Comment: "...arrow claiming cables pull air …" I honestly don't get that bit. There's no reason ATX is built to that design except that "they always have been". The only change in a decade or more is that they now mainly mount the PSU at the bottom instead of the top. There's also been some attempt to get the cabling out of the way, which unfortunately means you now need to take both sides off to mount anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just checking the specifications of these cases.
The first two already don't fit your cooler. Neither does the Sharkoon pure steel or the  corsair 110Q, so check the rest to see if they support the cooler height.
There are rtx3080 models of more than 330mm. There are also cases that do not support this, if you want optimal compatibility for all 3080 models, check for this.

Second I suggest picking the case with a mesh front and at least two fans preinstalled. preferably three.
Personally I recommend avoiding Sharkoon products. The ones I've worked in were very thin and had a lot of sharp edges that can cut your fingers or cables.

the masterbox mesh is an example of a good case in your list.
Mesh front, enough preinstalled fans, enough clearance for the cpu cooler(barely, but that's the nature of a cooler like the nh-d15) and a layout where adding hard drives does not reduce space for gpu so it supports all available options.